# Milah Without P'ri'ah

Tags: halacha, brit-milah

If a Jewish boy received a milah without p'ri'ah by a Jewish doctor, halakhically does he need to get more cutoff later in life? Preference for Sephardic sources.

When I asked a Rabbi he said there are opinions on which to rely for not needing further circumcision, but he didn't cite anything. When asked for sources he recommended checking Sefer haBrit.

Answer (score 7):

The Mishna (Shabbat 19:6) states:

> מל ולא פרע את המילה, כאלו לא מל.‏
>   If he did Milah but not Priah, it is as if he didn't do Milah.

Rambam (Milah 2:4) and Shulchan Arukh (YD 264:4) rule accordingly.

Comment: The Rambam and Mishna you cited is for the person performing the circumcision. Not the one who had it performed on him.

Comment: I'm not sure how you know that or what difference it makes.